# Why can't you do a DML on a map directly?

Tags: apex

Why can't you perform a DML directly on a Map? Why do you have to do `upsert myMap.values()` instead?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Couple of thoughts...

APIs are usually designed to be [Small and Focused](http://tutorials.jenkov.com/api-design/small-and-focused.html) and it is easy for the caller to extract the `values()` list from the map.

The signature of the [Database.upsert](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_database.htm?search_text=Database) method is:

```
UpsertResult[] upsert(sObject[] recordsToUpsert);
```

If a map argument was supported the results would also need to be put in a map. So cleaner to leave it to the caller to take the `values()` list from the map and pass that in.

Answer (score 5):

If you are trying to update a map of records in which the key is the Id of the object and the value is the object itself, then it is because **in order to update a record you need its Id**. If you are inserting, then the Id is null, but you would have only one record in the value.

But a shorter answer is: because the language was designed like that. Honestly, one can answer your question with 100% accuracy only if one worked on Salesforce's server-side, with the Apex compiler.

Comment: Eh. I would say your short answer *is* 100% accurate. That's not how they designed the language. If the question were about why they designed the language the way they did, it would be purely speculative and clearly off-topic.

Answer (score 2):

I'd assume that you are referencing a map as of `Map<Id, sObject>`, from where `values()` method returns list of sObject records, and this is what `Upsert Statement` is expecting as an argument - either a `List<sObject>`, or single `sObject` record. Here is the reference for [Apex DML Operations](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_dml_section.htm#apex_dml_upsert):

> The upsert DML operation creates new records and updates sObject
>   records within a single statement, using a specified field to
>   determine the presence of existing objects, or the ID field if no
>   field is specified.
>
> **Syntax**
>
> `upsert sObject​​ [opt_field]`
>
> `upsert sObject[]*​​ [opt_field]`

*`sObject[]` and `List<sObject>` is the same as list of sObject records